# FB Object Debugger でWe're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: facebook, open-graph-protocol

Facebookのオブジェクトデバッガーで以下のURLをチェックしたところ
https://makeyourownemblem.herokuapp.com/showemblem/2
「We're sorry, but something went wrong」
と出てしまい、全くOGPタグを認識しません。

これは何が悪いのでしょうか？ちなみにOGPはこんな感じです。どこも悪くなさそうに見えます。

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Make Your Own Emblem" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://makeyourownemblem.herokuapp.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://makeyourownemblem.herokuapp.com/assets/makeyourownemblem-6b8a416ab775207c550c1ed587fdfc250bca16ff190fef9bc8bb5b8f40630f1f.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Make Your Own Emblem" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This App Make Your Emblem. You might be able to submit this instead of existing candidate for 2020!!" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="ja_JP" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="618693892" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1659344774309585" />
```

どなたかご存知のかたよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくRuby on Railsで作成中の Webアプリケーションかと思いますが、それのエラー(500)です。
エラーメッセージですのでOGPタグも含まれていない筈です。問題のURLにブラウザでアクセスして確認してみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
なぜかOGPのURLを直したら改善されました。